# How can I use imshow to display multiple images in multiple windows?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to do something like the following in order to display two images on the screen:

```
imshow("1", img1);
imshow('2', 'img2');
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show multiple (2,3,4,…) images in the same window in OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089927/show-multiple-2-3-4-images-in-the-same-window-in-opencv)

Comment: many duplicates available!

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is possible. The function `void imshow(const string& winname, InputArray mat)` displays an image in the specified window, where -

- winname – Name of the window.
- image – Image to be shown.

The window is identified by its name. So to display two images(img1, img2), in two different window; use `imshow` with different name like :-

```
imshow("1",img1);
imshow("2",img2);
```

Comment: Do you know if this is possible in Python with the cv2 bindings? When I call imshow right after one another it kills the process.

Comment: yes i would like to know python equivalent code as well. Two succesive calls to cv2.imshow does not put up two windows

Answer (score 7):

I have this working in Python, with a caveat:

```
cv2.imshow("image 1", my_image_1)
cv2.imshow("image 2", my_image_2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The caveat is that both windows are in the exact same spot on the screen, so it only *looks* like one window opened up (Ubuntu 14.4). 
I can mouse drag one to the side of the other.

I'm now looking for how to place the two side by side automagically, which is how I found this question..

Comment: You can move the window like this: cv2.moveWindow("image 2", 0, 0)

Answer (score 5):

And here is how to do it in Python:

```
    cv2.namedWindow("Channels")
    cv2.imshow("Channels", image_channels)

    cv2.namedWindow("Main")
    cv2.imshow("Main", image_main)
```

You simply create a named window and pass its name as string to imshow.

Comment: I'm using jupyter and cv2.imshow doesn't show anything whereas plt.imshow() works.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the problem of having to create an arbitrary number of openCV windows. I had them stored in a list and couldn't simply loop over it to display them:

```
# images is a list of openCV image object

for img in images:
    cv2.imshow('image',i)
```

This doesn't work for the trivial reason of images requiring a different label, hence this loop would only display the last item in the list.

That can be solved by using an iterator and python string formatters:

```
for i, img in enumerator(images):
    cv2.imshow("Image number {}".format(i), img)
```

Therefore now all images will be displayed since they have been assigned a different label.

Comment: You meant ***enumerate*** (in the 2nd snippet).

Answer (score 0):

If your images are in numpy arrays, you could use numpy.hstack function which merges two arrays into a single and use the cv2.imshow() to display the array.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html

Answer (score -2):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

towImage = np.vstack((row_0, row_1))
cv2.imwrite('img', twoImage)
```

I create a module to make the modules easier to display

https://github.com/saman202/View_image_video_matrix

```
smp = ShowMatrixPic(width=180, height=240, row=3, column=4, atuoTile=True)
  

imgListOne = ['pic/Scott Glenn.jpg','pic/Brad Pitt.jpg',
              'pic/Scott Glenn.jpg','pic/Brad Pitt.jpg',
              'pic/Scott Glenn.jpg','pic/Brad Pitt.jpg',
              'pic/Scott Glenn.jpg','pic/Brad Pitt.jpg',
              'pic/Scott Glenn.jpg','pic/Brad Pitt.jpg'
              ]
numpy_horizontal = smp.showPic(imgListOne)
cv2.imshow('img', numpy_horizontal)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E3b5.png

Comment: Does this use one window or multiple windows?