# Speed up live plotting of a footage (cv2)

Tags: python, matplotlib, opencv3.0

I am attempting to use the cv2 module to create a live scatter plot for each frame of a video. The code below does exactly that.

However with more than 8 minute of footage containing more than 60000 frames to process, the code is not efficient and does take much longer than necessary to get the desired output.

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(filepath)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
plt.ion()

x=df["time"][7:100]
y=df["force"][7:100]

for i in range(len(x)):
   vidcap.set(1,590)
   ret, image = vidcap.read()
   frameId = vidcap.get(1) 
   plt.imshow(image,extent=[0,200,0,100], aspect='auto')
   plt.subplot(221)
   plt.plot(x[0+i:1+i],y[0+i:1+i],'or', lw=2)
   plt.subplot(222)
   fig.set_size_inches(20, 10)
   plt.pause(.000001)
   plt.draw()
```

I have considered using pyqtgraph to increase the speed of the process. Is there a better way to process and plot on a frame of a video?

Comment: This seems to be closely related to what is shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598124/update-frame-in-matplotlib-with-live-camera-preview)'s answer, the main point being not to recreate the complete plot on every iteration. If using the second approach from that answer, the use of `blit=True` may increase speed even more.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest How can I best avoid creating plot on every iteration? It is not clear how I can replace and implement `blit=True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598124/update-frame-in-matplotlib-with-live-camera-preview)'s answer shows two ways to obtain a video in matplotlib.

The main point is not to recreate the complete plot on every iteration. If using the second approach from that answer, the use of `blit=True` may increase speed even more. This is shown in the below code.

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

df = pd.DataFrame({"time": np.linspace(0,20, num=100), 
                   "force" : np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100))})

def grab_frame(cap):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    return frame # or cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#Initiate 
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# vidcap.set(1,590)

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(20, 10))

x=df["time"][7:100]
y=df["force"][7:100]

#create two image plots
im1 = ax.imshow(grab_frame(vidcap),extent=[0,200,0,100], aspect='auto')
line, = ax2.plot(x[0:1],y[0:1],'or')
ax2.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
ax2.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())

def update(i):
    im1.set_data(grab_frame(vidcap))
    line.set_data(x[0+i:1+i],y[0+i:1+i])
    return im1, line


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(x), interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```