# How can I use matplotlib in real-time?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matplotlib

I used Opencv to open my camera, then I want to show the image bu matplotlib.
However, the frames freezes.
Can I use matplotlib in real-time?
Thank you!

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    
while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    plt.subplot(1,2,1), plt.imshow(frame, interpolation='nearest')  
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `plt.ion()` to enable interactive plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    
plt.ion()

while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    plt.subplot(1,2,1), plt.imshow(frame, interpolation='nearest')  
    plt.pause(0.001)
    plt.show()
```

In this solution you replot everything and even create a new subplot for each frame to be shown. This is highly inefficient and hence slow. Check out this answer [Speed up live plotting of a footage (cv2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586983/speed-up-live-plotting-of-a-footage-cv2).

Comment: It works! Thank you! And plt.pause(0.001), how can I change the 0.001 to make the real time faster?

Comment: It'll be slower because of matplotlib plt. I dont think reducing the delay will improve it much.

Comment: In this solution you replot everything and even create a new subplot for each frame to be shown. This is highly inefficient. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586983/speed-up-live-plotting-of-a-footage-cv2) on how to prevent this. I marked as duplicate of it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for letting me know. I edited my answer.