# Display frames of video after processing (one by one) Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, video, opencv, imshow

If I have clip and need to process each frame and then show frames (display them). I found many examples on how you can get frames of clip and then save (write) them as new video. 
However, I tried to iterate on each frame and then show each processed image, but the Matplotlib show only one image after the loop finished.

```
clip = VideoFileClip(filename)
for frame in clip.iter_frames():
    new_frame= Fun(frame)
    plt.imshow(new_frame)
```

[update frame in matplotlib with live camera preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598124/update-frame-in-matplotlib-with-live-camera-preview)

I found this link but it uses frames from the camera, I need to display processes images as they received from the Fun one by one. So I don't want to save it or create a list of processed frames and then show them, I need to do it one by one.

I used the second method from the link, but it prints only 0, 0 and only shows the first frame! It seems it can't change the index to go to the next frame!

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
index =0


inF=[]
for frames in clip.iter_frames():
    inF.append(frames)

global inF


def grab_frame():
    print(index)
    frame = inF[index]
    return cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#Initiate the two cameras
cap1 = clip
#create two subplots
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)

#create two image plots
im1 = ax1.imshow(grab_frame())

def update(i):
    global index
    im1.set_data(grab_frame())
    index+=1


ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), update, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

Could you please help me? Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually try the suggestion there? I do not see any reason why reading from camera or from a video directly makes a difference. The point there is interactive plot and using plt.pause. In your case you can use framerate value for pause. For grab_frame(cap2), you just supply new_frame.

Comment: @Dinesh Thank you. I tried the second approach from the link. But I have the problem which I mentioned in the question. I edited it. Could you please check it?

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting any error? If it only prints `0,0` instead of a long list of numbers, the animation isn't actually running at all. So please either provide a [mcve] or at least the error message you get.

Comment: I don't have any error message. These numbers represent the output.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for comment. So posting as answer.

I read a video file directly using a library. It is working as desired. The color BGR2RGB is working as desired and the frames are changing and plays up to last frame.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import skvideo.io

index =0
inF=skvideo.io.vread('test.avi')


#inF=[]
#for frames in clip.iter_frames():
 #   inF.append(frames)

global inF


def grab_frame():
    print(index)
    frame = inF[index]
    return cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#Initiate the two cameras
cap1 = clip
#create two subplots
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)

#create two image plots
im1 = ax1.imshow(grab_frame())

def update(i):
    global index
    im1.set_data(grab_frame())
    index+=1


ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), update, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

There is no issue with above code. The source of error is your video or how you read your video. Obviously, it prints 0 to 32 (no. of frames in test.avi).

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh
Unfortunately, I got the same result of 0,0! seems that the animation doesn't work :(