# Display more images in one window with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem with OpenCV, I simply want to display more images on my screen with a code like this:

```py
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('img1.png')
img2=cv2.imread('img2.png')

cv2.imshow('Image 1',img)
cv2.imshow('Image 2',img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but it display only the second image, and if i add a `cv2.waitKey(0)` after the first `cv2.imshow()` it display them sequentially but I need both the images at the same time on the screen.

I tried to use new and old OpenCV and python versions but I have the same problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show multiple (2,3,4,…) images in the same window in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089927/show-multiple-2-3-4-images-in-the-same-window-in-opencv)

Comment: Is it an option to merge the images into one larger image and display the merged one?

Comment: @Daniele. It worked on Linux.